# Разделить массив согласно условию

Tags: c++

Задание  звучит так: Отсортировать массив таким образом, что бы сначала шли элементы которые отличаются от максимального на 20%, а потом все остальные, с помощью библиотеки algorithm
и контейнера vector

```
void sortMax20 (vector<int>& vec)
{
    auto maxnum = max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    cout << "Max num = " << *maxnum << endl;
    partition(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto& em) {return em + (em * 0,2) >= 9; });
}
```

Я решил сделать это с помощью алгоритма partition но вместо 9 в условии у меня должно быть переменная maxnum, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте захват, примерно так:

```
partition(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [maxnum](auto& em) {return em + (em * 0,2) >= *maxnum; });
```

и не забывайте, что `max_element` возвращает не значение, а итератор.